# TypeError: 'float' object has no attribute '__getitem__'. (Python)

Tags: python, tkinter

```
import Tkinter
import tkMessageBox
from Tkinter import *

CanvasHeight = 500
CanvasWidth = 600
```

Canvas width and height set to 10x the maximum of the variables.
    IsGraphHidden = 0

```
MainWindow = Tkinter.Tk()
```

This is the window for all the sliders, and is defined as "MainWindow" for later use.

```
Strength = DoubleVar() 
Multiple = DoubleVar()
Time = DoubleVar()
```

All of the variables set to DoubleVar, because of the Tkinter plugin. 
It needs it's own special floats, integers and strings to work. 
They can be accessed as normal variables by using VARIABLE.get()

```
coords = []
lastcoords = [0,0]
```

This is what we'll use to continue the line instead of just having a bunch of lines drawing themselves from the corner of the screen.

```
Plot = DoubleVar()

StrengthScale = Scale( MainWindow, variable = Strength, orient = HORIZONTAL,label="Strength")

MultipleScale = Scale( MainWindow, variable = Multiple, from_ = float(0), to = float(1), resolution = float(0.01), orient = HORIZONTAL, label="Multiple")

TimeScale = Scale( MainWindow, variable = Time, orient = HORIZONTAL, from_ = int(0), to = int(120), label="Time")
```

These are the procedures for the buttons, as well as the rest of the code.

```
def Calculate():
  answer = float(Strength.get())*float(Multiple.get())
  tkMessageBox.showinfo("Answer:", answer)

def PrepPlot():
 global IsGraphHidden
 global coords
 global lastcoords
 lastcoords0 = lastcoords[0]
 lastcoords1 = lastcoords[1]
 coords.append(lastcoords0)
 coords.append(lastcoords1)
 coords.append(Time.get()*5)
 coords.append(Strength.get()*Multiple.get()*5)
 lastcoords = Time.get()*5
 lastcoords = Strength.get()*Multiple.get()*5

if IsGraphHidden == 0:
 Graph = Canvas(MainWindow, width = CanvasWidth, height = CanvasHeight, bg = "white")
 Graph.create_line(coords, fill = "black")
 Graph.grid(row=5, column=1)
else:
 Graph.destroy()
 Graph.delete("all")
 Graph.create_line(coords, fill = "black")
 Graph.grid(row=5,column=1)
 IsGraphHidden = 1

def DisplayPoints():
 PointWindow = Tkinter.Tk()
 Text = Label(PointWindow, textvariable = "Hi there", relief=RAISED)
 Text.pack()
 PointWindow.mainloop() #Work in progress, nothin' to see here.

Button = Tkinter.Button(MainWindow, text= "Calculate",command = Calculate)
PrepButton = Tkinter.Button(MainWindow, text = "Plot", command = PrepPlot) #The text is the text on the button.
DisplayButton = Tkinter.Button(MainWindow, text = "Display Plots", command = DisplayPoints)

MultipleScale.grid(row=0,column=0)
StrengthScale.grid(row=1,column=0)
TimeScale.grid(row=1,column=2)
PrepButton.grid(row=2,column=1)
Button.grid(row=4,column=1)
DisplayButton.grid(row=3,column=1)

MainWindow.mainloop()
```

I need some help with the float object getitem error, I'm doing this code for work experience at Manchester university...

Comment: So **where** is the error raised? Please include the full traceback for the exception.

Comment: Note that you don't need to use `int()` and `float()` on literal values. `0` is *already* an integer, `0.01` is already a floating point object. `int()` and `float()` are for conversions, Python doesn't need type declarations.

Answer (score 4):

You replaced the `lastcoords` list with a floating point value:

```
lastcoords = Time.get()*5
lastcoords = Strength.get()*Multiple.get()*5
```

so that next time around the line:

```
lastcoords0 = lastcoords[0]
```

raises your exception as you cannot use subscription on a floating point value.

I *think* you wanted to set a new list instead:

```
lastcoords = [Time.get() * 5, Strength.get() * Multiple.get() * 5]
```

Comment: Thanks, I would rate up but I don't have the rep. :D